# DAX: get multiple values using Lookup function within a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, lookup-tables

I have a table as below image

[image]

I am using Employee Name column as a slicer in my report.

By using the below dax i am able to get the Supervisor name with lookupvalue funtion.

```
ManagerName = LOOKUPVALUE('HR View'[Employee Name],'HR View'[PersNo.],[Supervisor ID])
```

But I would like to get the output as,

If i am choosing an employee name from slicer

For ex:-

If i choose J

Then i should get the output as

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mohan V

Comment: Can you explain your output?

Comment: Here J is connected with F because his manager id is 6 and
F is connected with E because his manager id is 5.
like wise it will traversed to back, to view his complete hierarchy level.
And at the same time
if i choose E, his upper hierarchy is, B and A
and his lower hierarchy is I(9)

Is it possible??